# Contraddistinguere verso

Tags: word-meaning, word-choice, prepositions, single-words, word-order

Ho trovato il seguente testo in un libercolo:

> Il presente lavoro evita la noia che ha sempre contraddistinto intere generazioni verso il solfeggio.

Ho cercato il significato di contraddistinguere nel vocabolario Treccani, ma non capisco "contraddistinguere verso"

Verso qui significa "portare all'adozione di", o "aver una attitudine contro"? Sono confuso. Cosa significa questa preposizione?

Comment: “libercolo” ha un connotato spregiativo e indica un libro che non vale niente: intendevi questo oppure “libriccino” o simili?

Comment: Fai finta che ci sia scritto libricino.

Comment: A me, personalmente, quella frase sembra molto poco fluida. Se la trovassi in un mio lavoro, la riscriverei.

Answer (score 5):

Forse la frase può esserti più comprensibile se consideri "verso" insieme alla "noia". "Contraddistinguere" significa, di solito, "caratterizzare". La frase quindi significa che il libricino "evita la noia nei confronti del solfeggio che ha sempre caratterizzato intere generazioni".